# Passing Value from one Gridview to another page Gridview

Tags: c#

Hello mates i have a page View All Applicants.aspx with gridview and a link button

i want to redirect to page View Applicant Detail.aspx when i click on link button and i want to show data in gridview on View Applicant Detail.aspx page based on the previous page values.

here is the code for View All Applicants.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="View All Applicants.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div><center>
        &nbsp;</center>
        <center style="background-color: silver">
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            <strong><span style="font-size: 16pt">List of All Applicants</span></strong></center>
        <center style="background-color: silver">
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True"
                >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PersonName" HeaderText="PersonName" SortExpression="PersonName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DegreeName" HeaderText="DegreeName" SortExpression="DegreeName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="InstituteName" HeaderText="InstituteName" SortExpression="InstituteName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ExperienceYears" HeaderText="ExperienceYears" SortExpression="ExperienceYears" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrganizationName" HeaderText="OrganizationName" SortExpression="OrganizationName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" SortExpression="Designation" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Applicant Detail">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Cancel"
                                OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" Text="View"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString8 %>"
                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString8.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Distinct PERSONALDETAIL.PersonName, DEGREE.DegreeName, INSTITUTE.InstituteName, EXPERIENCE.ExperienceYears, EXPERIENCE.OrganizationName, EXPERIENCE.Designation FROM EXPERIENCE, EXPERIENCE EXPERIENCE_1, PERSONALDETAIL, DEGREE, INSTITUTE WHERE EXPERIENCE.ExperienceID = EXPERIENCE_1.ExperienceID">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center style="background-color: silver">
            &nbsp;</center>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and for View Applicant Detail.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="View Applicant Detail.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div><center>
        &nbsp;</center>
        <center style="background-color: silver">
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            <strong><span style="font-size: 16pt">Job Applicant Detail</span></strong></center>
        <center style="background-color: silver">
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ResumeID"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ResumeID" HeaderText="ResumeID" InsertVisible="False"
                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ResumeID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalExperienceYears" HeaderText="TotalExperienceYears"
                        SortExpression="TotalExperienceYears" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalExperienceMonths" HeaderText="TotalExperienceMonths"
                        SortExpression="TotalExperienceMonths" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ExperienceSummary" HeaderText="ExperienceSummary" SortExpression="ExperienceSummary" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DetailedCVName" HeaderText="DetailedCVName" SortExpression="DetailedCVName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AdditionalQualification" HeaderText="AdditionalQualification"
                        SortExpression="AdditionalQualification" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ExtraCurricular" HeaderText="ExtraCurricular" SortExpression="ExtraCurricular" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Skills" HeaderText="Skills" SortExpression="Skills" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TentativeFromDate" HeaderText="TentativeFromDate" SortExpression="TentativeFromDate" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PageIndex" HeaderText="PageIndex" SortExpression="PageIndex" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PersonalDetailID" HeaderText="PersonalDetailID" SortExpression="PersonalDetailID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartmentID" HeaderText="DepartmentID" SortExpression="DepartmentID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DesignationID" HeaderText="DesignationID" SortExpression="DesignationID" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString5 %>"
                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString5.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [RESUME]">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center>
            &nbsp;</center>
        <center style="background-color: silver">
            &nbsp;</center>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do a postbask to redirect the user to the details page, you can edit your template column to go directly to the URL of the details page along with a GET variable of the ID needed for the lookup.

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Applicant Detail">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="DetailsView.aspx?ResumeID=" + "<%# Bind("ResumeID") %>" Text="Visit W3Schools!" Target="_blank" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

In your Details page, do Request.QueryString("ResumeID") to get ID needed to do the lookup.